# Preserving key value pairs for duplicate keys when merging two Arrays to a hash

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays in ruby:

```
array_one = ["farmer_joe", "farmer_judy", "farmer_crazy_eyes", "farmer_joe"]

array_two = ["pigs", "chickens", "elephants", "cows"]
```

If I use the zip function I lose  the duplicate value, key pair for Farmer Joe.

```
hash_one = Hash[array_one.zip array_two] 

=> {"farmer_joe"=>"cows", "farmer_judy"=>"chickens", "farmer_crazy_eyes"=>"elephants"}
```

Ideally I want a function that allows me to overcome this in a nifty ruby flavoured oneline method. perhaps something like this that merges duplicate keys and adds their values to an array.

```
hash_one = Hash[array_one.super_special_zip array_two]

=> {"farmer_joe"=>["pigs","cows"], "farmer_judy"=>["chickens"], "farmer_crazy_eyes"=>["elephants"]}
```

Is there such a `super_special_zip` method? Or is there a good reason why this is a fools errand in the first place?

Comment: `array_one.zip array_two` does not lose the duplicates, turning the result into a Hash does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three standard ways of doing this.

```
a1 = ["farmer_joe", "farmer_judy", "farmer_crazy_eyes", "farmer_joe"]
a2 = ["pigs", "chickens", "elephants", "cows"]
pairs = a1.zip(a2) # or [a1,a2].transpose
  #=> [["farmer_joe", "pigs"], ["farmer_judy", "chickens"],
  #    ["farmer_crazy_eyes", "elephants"], ["farmer_joe", "cows"]]
```

**1. Use [Hash.new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) to create a hash with a default value of an empty array**

```
pairs.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] }) { |(f,l),h| h[f] << l }
  # => {"farmer_joe"=>["pigs", "cows"], "farmer_judy"=>["chickens"],
  #     "farmer_crazy_eyes"=>["elephants"]}
```

A variant of this (which tends to be slightly faster) is:

```
pairs.each_with_object({}) { |(f,l),h| (h[f] ||= []) << l }
```

**2. Use the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka merge!) that takes a block to determine the values of keys present in both hashes being merged**

```
pairs.each_with_object({}) { |(f,l),h| h.update(f=>[l]) { |_,o,n| o+n } }
  #=> {"farmer_joe"=>["pigs", "cows"], "farmer_judy"=>["chickens"],
  #    "farmer_crazy_eyes"=>["elephants"]}
```

**3. Use [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)**

```
h = pairs.group_by(&:first)
  #=> {"farmer_joe"=>[["farmer_joe", "pigs"], ["farmer_joe", "cows"]],
  #    "farmer_judy"=>[["farmer_judy", "chickens"]],
  #    "farmer_crazy_eyes"=>[["farmer_crazy_eyes", "elephants"]]} 
h.keys.each { |k| h[k] = h[k].map(&:last) }
h
  #=> {"farmer_joe"=>["pigs", "cows"], "farmer_judy"=>["chickens"],
  #    "farmer_crazy_eyes"=>["elephants"]}
```

There are many alternative to the last two lines, one being:

```
h.merge(h) { |*_,v| v.map(&:last) }
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it

```
array_one = ["farmer_joe", "farmer_judy", "farmer_crazy_eyes", "farmer_joe"]
array_two = ["pigs", "chickens", "elephants", "cows"]

hash_one = {}

array_one.each_with_index do |farmer,i|
    if hash_one.has_key?(farmer)
        hash_one[farmer] << array_two[i]
    else
        hash_one[farmer] = [array_two[i]]
    end
end

hash_one # => {"farmer_joe"=>["pigs", "cows"], "farmer_judy"=>["chickens"], "farmer_crazy_eyes"=>["elephants"]}
```

Comment: similar to above, I'd say this is a bit clearer but I like Cary's one-liner. If I can't get a magic built in `super_special_zip` method, the above would probably work well. Many thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 1):

And yet another way to do that would be ( no rails )

```
a1 = ["farmer_joe", "farmer_judy", "farmer_crazy_eyes", "farmer_joe"]
a2= ["pigs", "chickens", "elephants", "cows"]

a1.zip(a2).group_by(&:first).map{|key, value| [key, value.map(&:last)]}.to_h

# => {"farmer_joe"=>["pigs", "cows"], "farmer_judy"=>["chickens"], "farmer_crazy_eyes"=>["elephants"]}
```